# get url page template

Tags: page-template, site-url

I have created a page template where I need current page URL

I have tried

```
get_site_url();
```

and

```
get_permalink();
```

but it shows nothing.

Let me know is anything missing in code.

Comment: You meant [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) or a normal template?

Comment: custom page template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using a page template, then if you want to get the current page URL you could try to use this function:

```
get_permalink();
```

or

```
echo get_permalink();
```

if you want to print the result

Comment: no change, same

Answer (score 0):

You can get page url like this.

```
global $post;
echo get_permalink( $post->ID );
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: `$post` may be overwritten by a secondary query, in this case [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) is safer and avoids accessing globals directly.

Comment: global variable must not be overwritten that's the bad practise.

Comment: Using the API overwrites `$post`, that's how `the_post` works. Use API functions when available rather than relying on global variables.