# Getting post URL within custom content template

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, query-posts, the-content

This should be such an easy thing but it's giving me so much headache.

I created a content template called content-sticky.php.

Added all the code there

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('pinned-post teal'); ?>>
    <div class="pinned-post-image">
        <?php my_webpage_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>

    <header class="entry-header pinned-post-content">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
            ?>
            <p>
            <?php
            my_webpage_posted_on();
            my_webpage_posted_by();
            ?>
            </p>

            <?php
            the_excerpt();
            ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <a class="pinned-post-read-more rust" href="<?php 
    global $post;
    esc_url( get_permalink(($post->ID) ) );
    ?>">Read More</a>

</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Yes I know, I should not have the_excerpt in the header, that's a change for another day.

What I can't get to work is getting the permalink for the post, it returns empty! (tried [solutions from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233616/get-url-page-template))

[image]

I tried the following example after reading [the api](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/):

```
    <a class="pinned-post-read-more rust" href="<?php esc_url( get_permalink(the_ID()) )?>">Read More</a>
```

It returned `href="1234"` which is the correct ID but not the permalink, so how was the correct ID passed and not the return a URL?

I thought because it was a string? so I casted with an int `(int) the_ID()`, same result...

I'm lost.

I haven't really studyied php either so that might be a reason, just going on with my modest knowledge from C, Python, Java, and Javascript

BTW, this is how I'm implementing this template

```
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); // Get all sticky posts

    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post__in'  => $sticky,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div id="pinned-posts">
            <div class="tab-header" id="pinned-posts-tab-header">Pinned Posts</div> <?php

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <?php
            endif;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                $query->the_post();

                /*
                * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-sticky', get_post_type() );

            endwhile;

        else:

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
        
        ?> </div> <?php
        wp_reset_query();
        endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch `get_permalink` to `the_permalink` or `echo esc_url(get_permalink)`.

[get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

[the_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/)

Comment: the_permalink() worked thank you.